# assembly multiply 16 bit unsigned print product

Tags: assembly, irvine32, masm32

I want to use 16bit multiply to get the square value.
I use Irvine32.
This is my code:

```
mov ax,2
mov bx,2
mul ax

Call WriteDec
```

Suppose it is 2 squared, but it is printed as 8912900.

How can I write out the product?
I know the instruction is:

Multiplicand / Multiper  / Product

AX     /      reg/mem16  /  DX:AX

Comment: Use 32 bit multiplication :)  But if you insist, you will have to pack `dx` into the top 16 bits of `eax` for printing. Or, if you only want a 16 bit result, zero the top 16 bits.

Comment: Check the documentation of the Irvine32 library and find out where to place the number to print.

Comment: It's `eax`. The problem is he did not set the top 16 bits.

Comment: After that, I will judge whether it overflows, so I still use 16 bits for multiplication.

Comment: After that, what is your remaining problem?

Comment: Will print 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, ...  Until the overflow.